# Why does render resolution affect RAM use?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, performance

I am trying to understand all the factors that effect RAM use so I can get the most out of my graphics cards VRAM when rendering. I understand that the amount of geometry and the resolution of textures make a big difference. However, I do not understand why render resolution does. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image that is rendered need to go in the ram, so bigger image need more ram, have a look here: [View Memory Usage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33206/view-memory-usage/67039#67039) There are other points like adaptive subdiv, but I'm not a specialist of these kind of questions.